# Pandas - Sort dataframe by highest individual value in any column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data formatted like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Steve', '3', '2'],
                        ['Smith', '4', '3'],
                        ['Scott', '0', '5'],
                        ['Simon', '1', '8']],
                  columns=['Name', 'Count1', 'Count2'])
```

Sorting it with `df.sort_values(by=['Count1','Count2'], ascending=[False,False], inplace=True)` returns this

```py
    Name Count1 Count2
1  Smith      4      3
0  Steve      3      2
3  Simon      1      8
2  Scott      0      5
```

I want to get the rows with the highest individual value of **any** column to the top.
This is my expected output:

```py
    Name Count1 Count2
3  Simon      1      8
2  Scott      0      5
1  Smith      4      3
0  Steve      3      2
```

What would be the appropriate way of going about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC `argsort`

```
df = df.iloc[(-df.drop('Name',1).max(axis=1)).argsort()]
    Name Count1 Count2
3  Simon      1      8
2  Scott      0      5
1  Smith      4      3
0  Steve      3      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
result = df.assign(order=df.iloc[:, 1:].max(axis=1)).sort_values('order', ascending=False).drop('order', axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
    Name Count1 Count2
3  Simon      1      8
2  Scott      0      5
1  Smith      4      3
0  Steve      3      2
```

As an alternative:

```
order = df.drop('Name', axis=1).max(1).sort_values(ascending=False).index
result = df.iloc[order]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute the max of the columns, and then sort and reference the index.

```py
df.iloc[df.iloc[:, 1:].max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index]
```

```
    Name Count1 Count2
3  Simon      1      8
2  Scott      0      5
1  Smith      4      3
0  Steve      3      2
```